# How do I set View ids when accessing children of View when using ViewBinding instead of Kotlin Synthetics?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I am updating an Android project to use `ViewBinding` instead of `Kotlin Synthetics`.  I'm having difficulty figuring out how to change the following code so I can access the views from their layout IDs.

```
binding.myLinearLayout.children
            .filter { it.checkboxInput is CheckBox }
```

In this case `children` are all generic `View` types and can't access the `checkboxInput` IDs like it used to be possible using `Kotlin Synthetics`.

I get the error `Unresolved reference: checkboxInput`

What would be the way to solve this?  Is there a way to check if the View is of a binding type?  Do I need to make custom View classes to do this?  Any other ideas?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

I have another case that's a bit confusing.

```
binding.formItems.children
        .filter { it.getTag(R.id.tag_guest_identifier) != null }
        .map { view ->
            Guest(
                guestIdentifier = view.getTag(R.id.tag_guest_identifier).toString(),
                name = view.playerName.valueText.toString(),
                ...
            )
        }
}
```

Here, I get a list of generic `View`s so I can't access their properties (ie. view.playerName... etc.).

Do I need to create a View subclass and then cast the view to that type?  Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View binding works basically the same way synthetics did, except when you have something with an ID of `checkbox_input`, instead of magically creating a variable called `checkboxInput` on the `Activity` or whatever, it creates it in the `ViewBinding` object instead. So if you were accessing it like this before:

```
// not declared anywhere, it's just magically there for you to use
checkboxInput
```

now you access it on the `ViewBinding` object instead:

```
binding.checkboxInput
```

You don't need to do any searching, that defeats the point of view binding! It's automagically binding views to variables in a convenient object.

Your code would work with `filter { it is CheckBox }`, and then you'd get all the `Checkbox` items within that part of the layout (you can also use `filterIsInstance<CheckBox>`, same thing). But if you wanted the one with a specific ID, you'd have to look at its ID attribute - and at that point, might as well just use `findViewById`!

Comment: Thanks for you help!  I'm running into a similar issue and have updated my question.  For this I feel like I need to create a custom View and then check its type.  Is there another way?

Comment: @cheaze ``View`` is an Android class, it doesn't have a ``playerName`` property. Are you sure you don't just want to do ``binding.playerName``? That will give you the view (I'm guessing an ``EditText``) in your layout that has the ``playerName`` ID (or ``player_name``, it can do some conversions). Looping over the layout hierarchy, filtering out specific types is the kind of thing you do when you're *not* using IDs, which is what I assume ``playerName`` is?

Comment: Hi @cactustictacs, thanks for your help.  You're correct, `playerName` is an ID that I'm trying to access.  The issue is when accessing `binding.formItems.children` and mapping them, a generic `View` is returned and I can't access the `playerName` ID like was previously possible with synthetics.  Those views are inflated and added in code to `formItems` which is a `LinearLayout`.  I'm not sure how I can get access to the IDs.

Comment: @cheaze view binding classes are generated from layout XML files, so there's a reference to every view in the XML with an ID. If you're inflating views and adding them to the hierarchy manually at runtime, then they won't be accessible through view binding. ``findViewById`` will work though - this is literally the use case for it, finding a view by its ID! But if you're inflating views in code, you could always keep a reference to them, or set them up as you create them (sounds like you're already doing ``setId`` on them). Hard to know exactly what's happening without seeing your code though

Answer (score 0):

With viewBinding you can access views typing just

binding.viewId

Where viewId is the id defined for each view in your xml with the attribuite

android:id

In your case you can access the checkbox using

binding.checkboxInput